# There is this template and the file that contains the element I inspected missing in visual studio code and it appears in the developer tools instead

Tags: html

[image]

From the image, you see a successful inspection of an html element. The problem is the file the contains all the html found is not available when I open the code in VS code. What I did then is take class names found in the file in the developer tools and put them as search values in vs code but no html file containing the class names returned.

Comment: Can you post the folder structure of your site? Are the files even located in your local drive? Please edit your question to make it clearer. I am finding it hard to understand.

Comment: I believe they are because for it to run on the browser in the first place it has to be present. Catch is, from the image you can see the class="mega menu" on a <ul> tag and when I go back to vs code and search for "mega menu" in the folder structure, the results don't throw back any html file and you can see very clearly on inspection, it is in a html file.